# A Series Problem from Calculus-2 course

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This problem is from calculus-2 course. The basic knowledge includes integral test and $p$-series test.

Find an $N$ so that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over n^4}$$ is between $$\sum_{n=1}^N {1\over n^4}$$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^N {1\over n^4} + 0.005$$

The Answer is $N=5$.

How to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** use the fact that
$$
 \frac 1{(n+1)^4} <\int_n^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x^4} <\frac 1{n^4}
$$or, to be more accurately:
$$
\int_n^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x^4} <\frac 1{n^4} < \int_{n-1}^{n}\frac{dx}{x^4} 
$$

Comment: Who? I just come and see your answer.

Comment: How'd you derive that inequality?

Comment: @GFauxPas this is because the function $x\to 1/x^4$ decreases.

Comment: @mookid My solution is: ${1\over (N+1)^4}<0.005\Rightarrow N\ge4$, and I checked it by computer. Why the correct answer is $N=5$? Cheers!

Comment: @zhaoyin.usm you did not my hint. You have to evaluate the sum of the terms 1/n, not a single one!

Comment: @mookid What I mean is: $\sum_{n=1}^{4}{1\over n^4} < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1\over n^4} < \sum_{n=1}^{4}{1\over n^4}+0.005$, which is $1.078752 < 1.082323 < 1.083752$. Thus I think $N=4$ is the minimum answer of this problem but not $N=5$. How to solve your integral inequality?

Comment: @zhaoyin.usm use the inequality to estimate the sum from N instead